# MySQL Master bin file truncated

Tags: mysql

Our Master MySQL server disk filled and caused the server to crash, after resolving that the replication to the Slave was failing so we started the replication again.

After running 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;' and 'SHOW MASTER STATUS;' we noted the bin file and position.

On the Slave we set the correct bin file and position but MySQL errors with `'binlog truncated in the middle of event; consider out of disk space on master`

The bin file we are using is the last one created on the Master and no news ones appear to be being created.

Can anyone advise how I can resolve this and have new bin files created.

Thanks

Comment: can you please check free space on system first.

Comment: Disk check has been run and there is plenty of free space on the disk. Thanks

Comment: rechecked diskspace and have confirmed there are no issues with free space. Any other ideas ?

Comment: then might be relay log file got crashed, You need to start resync slave if you have binary logs available on master.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After a reboot a new bin file was created. Following that we got some 1062 errors but they were sorted and now it's all running.

Comment: reboot was not required. If you want new files then you can hit `flush logs;` which will create new log file. and if you start slave with exact log positions then 1062 shouldn't occur.